# PHP $_SESSION['username'] variable not being set

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm making a simple registration/login form using PHP linked to a MySQL database.
However when creating the login session, despite the user login details being verified correctly, whenever the session is being verified using the username session variable it is always returning false and when I check the session variable contents using print_r it shows that it contains nothing.

Here is a picture of my login code and the session verification code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8WSY.png

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Without posting your code, nobody can make any suggestions.

Comment: You need to use `session_start()` when you set the session as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start your session by adding `session_start()` above `$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];` in `login.php`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This fixed it. I did not know that session_start() had to be called at the top of every page that uses it, makes sense in hindsight. Will remember that for the future.

Comment: @Waypalm No problem :)